# Autocompletion for CakePHP finders in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cakephp, autocomplete, cakephp-4.x

is there a way in VScode to have autocompletion for custom finders when using `$this->Table->find('finderName')` ? Each time I have to check in the Table file to see which finder exists.

I tried using PHP doc when defining the finder function

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper/wiki/Visual-Studio-Code
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper should work fine as long as you have Intelephense Extension.